Unable to Register New Users in Firebase with Expo
I'm running into an issue with my Firebase project using Expo. When I try to register a new user, the system doesn't allow me to create a partition in the database with data beyond the user's email and password. It requires admin access to do this, but it wouldn't be practical to have only the admin registering new users. Does anyone know how Ienter image description here can fix this?enter image description here
i was trying to connect my firebase as a firestore so i could let the user register their information in the database in a secure way but it won't work because of a firebase admin rule. how can i solve this without losing the security of my application?.
even following the step-by-step tutorials doesn't work

Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

This might be due to the disabled user actions settings in Authentication page on Firebase console.
If Enable create (sign-up) is disabled, end-users (client-side app) are not allowed to create an account. See this documentation for your reference.


this option is enabled in my firebase  https://ibb.co/CM9FvcH

How about the email/password sign in provider? Is it enabled?

I don't know, I'm new to firebase and mobile development

Do you have discord? It would be easier for me to reply and send pictures of the code
